# SQL Cursor within Stored Procedure to populate string variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursors

I have a stored procedure that contains a cursor to loop through SQL records and populates the string which I will use later as my email text. I'm trying to print it out to verify before I can proceed with it but it seems to not populate the string. Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server 2005.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBody] 
AS
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @emailBody nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @statusName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @deptCode nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @instructors nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @meetingTime nvarchar(max)

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD For
Select StatusName, DeptCode, Instructors, Description from MyTable where StatusID = (select CAST(value AS INT) from Table2 where ConfigOption = 'RequiredStatus')

Open @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @statusName, @deptCode, @instructors, @meetingTime


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
 SET @emailBody = @emailBody + @statusName + ' ' + @deptCode + ' ' + @instructors + ' ' + @meetingTime 
 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @statusName, @deptCode, @instructors, @meetingTime

END
CLOSE @MyCursor
Print @emailBody

DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because @emailBody starts out as NULL, and any concatenation with NULL yields NULL by default.  Do a

```
SET @emailBody = '';
```

at the beginning of your script.

Also, strongly consider adding a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement at the top of your stored procedure -- not having NOCOUNT ON can greatly slow the execution of your proc.

Comment: This is one that can drive you nuts in SQL. NULL plus anything equals NULL and the default for strings is NULL. Great catch @Dave Markle!

Comment: Just click that little "check" button underneath the vote number when you get a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a cursor for this string concat. Wont the following query suffix

```
DECLARE @emailBody nvarchar(max) 

Set @emailBody = ''

Select @emailBody = @emailBody + StatusName + ' ' + DeptCode + ' ' + Instructors + ' ' + [Description] from MyTable where StatusID = (select CAST(value AS INT) from Table2 where ConfigOption = 'RequiredStatus')

Print @emailBody
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!